# seaborn gridplot/subplots to show one variable on the 1st column and another variable on 2nd column for the same row ID

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, subplot

I am trying to plot a seaborn gridplot subplot such that 
1. Each row of the figure/plot will have the graph of one client entity that am trying to plot.
2. The columns of this row will represent line plots of different variables of that same client.

So for instance, if there are client ABC, XYZ, PQR with historical income trend and historical expense trend,
I would like to plot

ABC's Income subplot and then expense subplot next to it

XYZ's Income subplot and then expense subplot next to it

PQRS's Income subplot and then expense subplot next to it.

I am able to plot the subplots for the same variable, however unable to include the second variable in the second column.
Any pointers would be extremely useful.

```
num_plots = len(clients)
fig,ax=plt.subplots(30,2,figsize=(12,96))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4,wspace=0.4)
for x in range(num_plots):
    df = dfABC[dfABC['Client'] == clients[x]]
    row = x//2
    col = x%2
    ax_curr = ax[row,col]
    sns.lineplot(data=df,x='Year',y='Income',ax=ax_curr).set_title(clients[x])
```

This is creates a 30 row by 2 columns plot with each plot only representing Income.
How can i have the Expense line plot as the 2nd column ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Data generation
clients = ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'PQR']
n_points = 1000
dfABC = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Client': np.random.choice(clients, size=n_points),
         'Year': np.random.choice([2010, 2011, 2012, 2013], size=n_points),
         'Income': np.random.exponential(size=n_points)*10,
         'Expense': np.random.exponential(size=n_points)})

# Figure generation
clients = list(dfABC['Client'].unique())
n_rows = len(clients)
fig,ax=plt.subplots(n_rows,2,figsize=(12,96))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4,wspace=0.4)
for i, client in enumerate(clients):
    df = dfABC[dfABC['Client'] == client]
    sns.lineplot(data=df,x='Year',y='Income',ax=ax[i, 0]).set_title(client)
    sns.lineplot(data=df,x='Year',y='Expense',ax=ax[i, 1]).set_title(client)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you advise how i can incorporate y axis formatting.
(for instance.. ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter())

Comment: ax[i, 0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter()), ax[i, 1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.EngFormatter()) in the loop will probably do the job.

Comment: however the same approach does not help if i have to change horizontal alignment of xaxis xticklabels :(